# Regular Expression Extract Multiple Values

Tags: javascript, regex

`/[.#]\s*([^{\s]*)\s*{/` Will get the text between the # or . and {.
I am trying to extract the text between the # or . and { as well as the text between the { and }. I believe it would be similar to the expression bellow.

```
var productText = '#id {} .class {}';
var m, r = /([.#]\s*([^{\s]*)\s*{)(([^{]*)}/)/g;
```

Comment: @acheong87 The expression returns null using an execute method in javascript but the actual expression i am looking for is somewhat similar to /([.#]\s*([^{\s]*)\s*{)(([^{]*)}/)/g.

Comment: @Jacob A well asked question. +1 Unsure if this applies, but don't leave your accepted answer swinging in the breeze -- if s/o downvotes him (and you think it injust), do him the service of upvoting also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex to get the part between # and {}

```
^\#(\S+\s+)\{\}.*
```

> NOTE: I have tried the regex only in Perl.
>         Also for remaining part of the regex i have simply put .* and not extracting the same.

Answer (score -1):

String.split is often easier to use for extraction, and even then a cleanup helper is useful:

```
var productText = '#id {123} .class {456}';
var m, r = /(:?[.#])([\w\W]+?)\s*\{([\w\W]+?)\s*\}/g;

productText.split(r).slice(2,-1).filter(/./.test, /\w/)
// output array: ["id", "123", "class", "456"]
```